# Method to Consolidate Cell Contents from Two Excel Files into One Excel File

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, cells, translation

I translated an Excel file in Chinese into English with OmegaT, a CAT (Computer-Aided Translation) tool, and a pure English file was generate by OmegaT.

However, the customer wants me to submit an Excel file in which all cells are filled with the source Chinese text and following English translation.

An example goes like [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s17/sh/4d5d0bc1-d318-46c7-9e49-adac848d493b/4ce88233cb8f2eeb30589ad04d176839).

Note : Amounts are not translated, and the Chinese and English contents are separated with a carriage return in each cell.

Is it possible to consolidate cell contents from the original Excel file and the translated Excel file? The structures of the two Excel files are identical. It will be better if cell contents could be checked for whether they are the same, and if they are the same, leave the original content as it is.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You _should_ be able to set up a third sheet with the formulae in the (combined) cells set to something like (for eg in Cell A1 of the combination sheet):  = concatenate(Chinese!A1, Char(10), English!A1) and copy down (or across) for the rest of the headings.  The rest of the sheet will equal the corresponding cell in either of the sheets (preferably the original) if you're confident they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sheet named `Chinese` and `English` are combined into `Combined`.

Basic formula: at cell A1 `=Chinese!A1&Char(10)&English!A1`
where `&` means concatenating two strings; `Char(10)` is the Line Feed character (i.e. next line)

If you want any numerical fields be skipped, slightly amend the formula to `=IF(ISNUMBER(Chinese!A1), Chinese!A1, Chinese!A1&Char(10)&English!A1)`
In that case, numeric fields will be copied from `Chinese` sheet without merging with `English` sheet.

Fill this formula everywhere you want the cells to be merged.

Comment: It works! But the consolidated cell is filled with zero (0) if both the original Chinese and English cells are blank when the if function is used. Is it possible to leave the consolidated cell blank when the original Chinese and English cells are both blank?

Comment: Since it is not possible for an Excel formula to return a true "empty cell" [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel] I could only come up with a close alternative: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(Chinese!A1), ISBLANK(English!A1)), "", IF(ISNUMBER(Chinese!A1), Chinese!A1, Chinese!A1&Char(10)&English!A1))`

Comment: @JamesHan if you find the answer useful, would you please accept the answer?  Thanks!